# Is there a way to access each individual permutation with itertools.permutations without adding everything to a list?

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

I am using Python, and I have a list of strings (around 30). I want to find all the possible permutations of them, and I am doing so with itertools.permutations. Basically what I want to do is after I get a permutation, I want to hash it using hashlib and check it against a certain value, which I am getting from a password.txt file before moving on to the next permutation. I don't necessarily want to go through another list of permuted strings and try and access all of them. I am not sure how to access each individual permutation at a time without going through another list, since I am not able to store it in a variable, because itertools.permutations returns a permutations object. I tried to use *map*, but am not sure if this works because my pyCharm doesn't result anything. Is there a way to do this? My code is below:

```
temp = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", 
"P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "1","2","3", "4","5"]

f = open("password.txt", "r") 

for i in range(10): 
    t = f.readline() 
    for i in range(1, len(temp) + 1): 
      for x in map("".join, itertools.permutations(temp, i)):
        encode = hashlib.md5(x.encode())
        hex = encode.hexdigest() 
        if fileLine.__contains__(hex): 
           print "Found"
```

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.permutations` returns a **generator**. Generators are generally intended to be iterated over **once**. If you want to iterate over it multiple times you can always store it in a list, just like that:

```
perm = list(itertools.permutations(temp, i))
```

The whole code you want would look like that:

```
temp = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "1","2","3", "4","5"]

f = open("password.txt", "r") 

for file_line in f:
    for i in range(1, len(temp) + 1):
        perm = list(itertools.permutations(temp, i))
    
        for p in perm:
            word = ''.join(p)
            encode = hashlib.md5(word.encode())
            hex = encode.hexdigest()

            if hex in file_line: 
                print "Found"
```

Also note that you shouldn't generally call methods named like `__contains__` directly - in this case you might want to use operator `in` instead. And watch out for var names - you've used `i` as index variable twice in nested loops.

Comment: I didn't want to make another list and loop through that, I wanted to check each permutation one by one.

Comment: 'check each permutation one by one' what exactly do you mean by that? From your code, I've understood that you wanted to check each line of the input file for every possible permutation of any possible length. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

itertools.permutations(temp, i) is already a generator, you don't need to list it, just define it once and iterate it with a for loop:

```
temp = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", 
"P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "1","2","3", "4","5"]

f = open("password.txt", "r") 
for _ in range(10): 
    t = f.readline() 
    for i in range(1, len(temp) + 1): 
        iterator = itertools.permutations(temp, i)
        for x in iterator:
            encode = hashlib.md5(x.encode())
            hex = encode.hexdigest() 
            if fileLine.__contains__(hex): 
                print("Found")
```

Two more things, this will still take for ever as the permutation number explodes quickly, second: are you using python 2.7? the print statement will fail in python 3.x.

Comment: When I run this it says "encode = hashlib.md5(x.encode())
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'"

Comment: @Programmer12345 try now.